# How do I validate a json field is formatted correctly using MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath?

Tags: regex, unit-testing, spring-boot

I'm trying to use a regexp to validate a value is formatted in a specific way, `Lastname, Firstname` (see comment where I'm making the format assertion).

The test I've written uses MockMvcResultMatchers. I can't find good documentation for this library, I can only see the API. So currently, I'm building a ResultMatcher with `jsonpath` assuming it will assert on the pattern matches and return me a boolean. But it only returns my the value of `$.name`.

Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. I've pasted a version of the test that demonstrates what I'm trying to do.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class SomeEntityControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private Pattern name = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z0-9_']+\\s?,\\s?[A-Za-z0-9_']+$");

    @Test
    public void getSomeEntityShouldReturnOkWithProperlyFormatted() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/someEntity/132")).andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").exists());
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", matches(name))); // <-- FORMAT ASSERTION NOT WORKING. Only getting the string value of $.name
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead, precisely? You hven't imported matches, so how could this even compile?

Comment: I'm expecting `andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", matches(name))); ` to return a boolean if the value of `name` is formatted correctly based on the regex. Instead, a string to string comparison on the value of `name` is being made against the `"^[A-Za-z0-9_']+\\s?,\\s?[A-Za-z0-9_']+$"`

Comment: Why would it return a boolean? Here's the javadoc: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/MockMvcResultMatchers.html. It returns a ResultActions, not a boolean. What does "a string to string comparison" mean? Your code doesn't even compile, because you haven't defined nor imported any matches() function. So how can you complain about its runtime behavior?

Comment: I'm looking for help on how to get the desired assertion -- the code is compiling fine I'm just unsure how to run `$.name` through the regex for validation on the format

Comment: Have you found out how to do this?

Comment: It's been a long time but, I don't think I resolved this one

Answer (score 7):

Use matchesPattern of Hamcrest library http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.0.0.0/org/hamcrest/text/MatchesPattern.html

```
String regex = "^[A-Za-z0-9_']+\\s?,\\s?[A-Za-z0-9_']+$";

@Test
public void getSomeEntityShouldReturnOkWithProperlyFormatted() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/someEntity/132")).andDo(print())
           .andExpect(status().isOk())
           .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").exists());
           .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", matchesPattern(regex)));
    }
```